# Dice roll animation

Tags: css, reactjs

I have built dice roll App in React [GitHub](https://github.com/austrisu/diceRollApp)

Everything works fine, but sometimes when I roll the dice random function returns the same number as previous, I can't figure out how to make some simple dice roll animation so it is distinguishable when dice have been rolled and number is just the same as previous.

You can have look on working app [here](http://dice-roll-11.herokuapp.com/)

I send external props to  function where I based on recieved number dice is displayed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './dice.css';
class Dice extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.diceFace()}
            </div>
        );
    }

    //runs CSS function depending on random number recieved
    diceFace = () => {
        switch(this.props.random) {
            case 1:
                return this.one();
            case 2:
                return this.two();
            case 3:
                return this.three();
            case 4:
                return this.four();
            case 5:
                return this.fiwe();
            case 6:
                return this.six();
            default:
                alert("smthing wrong")
        }
    }

    //********************************
    //CSS for dice faces
    //********************************

    one = () => {
        return(
            <div class="first-face">
                <span class="pip"></span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    two = () => {
        return(
            <div class="second-face">
                <span class="pip"></span>
                <span class="pip"></span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    three = () => {
        return(
            <div class="third-face">
                <span class="pip"></span>
                <span class="pip"></span>
                <span class="pip"></span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    four = () => {
        return(
            <div class="fourth-face">
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    fiwe = () => {
        return(
            <div class="fifth-face">
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    six = () => {
        return(
            <div class="sixth-face">
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                    <span class="pip"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


}


export default Dice;
```

Comment: well, it's rand behavior, its possible sometimes to throw twice the same number, this is not an issue, only set an animation to the dices when "roll the dice" button is pressed and it's done

Comment: I think .you've something wrong on the rand function, i can't see the number six on the dices anywhere. Using max number of dices i can't reach a total value of 30 or more (which 36 is supposed to be the max value) i rolled like 150 times and the max value i could reach was 27, and no 6 shown in 150 rolls on any dice

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I have already fixed it, I haven't deployed it yet.

Comment: @Austris can you check the proposed answer? It is a good habit to respond back them when people try to answer your issues.

Comment: There is nothing displayed on the mentioned Heroku App site anymore: http://dice-roll-11.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of animations to let user better understand that the dice has been rolled. I think, one of the most straight way of implementing animations on React is via the `npm`package called [`react-flip-move`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flip-move). You can just wrap your `React Component`or your `div element` with `FlipMove`. For example;

```
render() {
        return(
            <FlipMove>
                {this.diceFace()}
            </FlipMove>
        );
    }
```

You can implement other ways of animations, though.

Comment: I tried the way you have suggested , but this only animates when new dices are added or removed. This not solves problem when the same number is rolled so the some dice is displayed.